# How to Represent Type Information of External Symbols in a local Symbol Table?

Tags: parsing, scope, antlr

There are plenty of resources about building up symbol tables during parsing of source code, as long as the symbols are local. But how can external symbols be integrated, part. their type information, for a language that has imports?

Say, the current code (of a statically typed language) imports a module that exports some functions, variables and classes, and those symbols can be used directly in the current code (think of Java's "star" imports, or Python's `from foo import *`). For symbol resolution in the current code, it would be straight-forward to include the module's exported symbols in the current global scope, in order to look them up.

But the module could itself import other modules, and this could affect the exported symbols, specifically their types. If you want to maintain type information on your symbols you might need to recur into those other modules to look up those types, which in turn could import yet other relevant modules, and so forth.

While this recursive analysis would usually terminate, this could result in a huge scope tree being added to the local symbol table, to capture all involved types and to be able to validate expressions of the form `a.b.c...`. This would also make ahead-of-time scanning for exported symbols much more expensive.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach to this kind of dependency is to create one symbol table per module. Such a symbol table can be referenced from any number of other (module) symbol tables (including itself, which makes no sense, but would be possible). A simple list takes care to avoid endless recursion while resolving a symbol (seen modules). Since there's only one ST per module you will not create a huge ST tree, but a unique ST graph with at most as many nodes as there are modules involved.

For a concrete implementation see my [antlr4-vscode extension](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/backend/SourceContext.ts#L59) where I use a `SourceContext` class to cover all details for a single file (module). It contains a symbol table and source contexts as well as their symbol tables are interlinked to allow symbol (and other lookups) beyond the current context. However, in this implementation I don't need a recursion stopper, since ANTLR4 grammars are strictly organized as a tree (tokenVocab, import).

Comment: Thanks for the update with the example from your own code. I'm using ANTLR as well. I have to look into this and might come back if I have questions.

Comment: I hadn't realized you're the author of the Antlr plugin for VSCode. Great stuff! I installed it a couple of weeks ago, but hadn't gotten around using it much until now. The call graph feature is terrific!